# How to add validation for java script associative array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add validation for following java script associative array.

Here is my array structure

```
array = [
         { id: 1, remaining_amount: 30, total: 20 },
         { id: 1, remaining_amount: 30, total: 20 },
         { id: 2, remaining_amount: 50, total: 40 }
        ]
```

From the above array, for id 1, remaining amount is 30 but total amount is 40

So i want to add the validation that if total amount is grater then remaining amount for particular id then it will show me message.

Any Idea?

Comment: So the `remaining_amount` will always be the same on all array elements with the same `id`?

Comment: Yes it will be same with same id

Comment: Please check answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `filter`

Use `reduce`to summarise the total. and use `filter` to get all those array that `total` is greater than `remaining_amount`

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, remaining_amount: 30, total: 20 },{ id: 1, remaining_amount: 30, total: 20 },{ id: 2, remaining_amount: 50, total: 40 }];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.id] = c[v.id] || {id: v.id,remaining_amount: v.remaining_amount,total: 0};
  c[v.id].total += v.total;
  return c;
}, {})).filter(o => o.remaining_amount < o.total);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code -

```
array.forEach(function(obj) {

   if (obj.total > obj.remaining_amount) 
     console.log(`for id ${obj.id}, remaining amount is ${obj.remaining_amount} but total amount is ${obj.total}`);
});
```